# multiple if statements in a React.js component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

I am working on my portfolio and I bumped into this problem.
This component gets tasks(array) and sortBy(either 'all', 'true', or 'false').
The problem is, even though I pass 'all' value of sortBy, the second if statement gets called.

```
const TaskListTable = ({ tasks, sortBy }) => {
  let filteredTasks;
  let sortByBoolean;
  if (sortBy === 'all') {
    filteredTasks = tasks;
  }
  if (sortBy === 'true' || 'false') {
    sortByBoolean = sortBy === 'true';
    filteredTasks = tasks.filter((task) => task.completed === sortByBoolean);
  }
  console.log(sortBy);
  console.log(sortByBoolean);
  console.log(filteredTasks);

  const withTasks = (
    <div className='task-table'>
      <UtilButton purpose='add' pushUrl='/task-add' />
      <div className='task-table-head'>
        <div>Date</div>
        <div>Task</div>
        <div>Status</div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      {filteredTasks.map(({ _id, ...others }) => (
        <TaskList key={_id} id={_id} {...others} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
  const withoutTasks = <UtilPage purpose='emptyData' />;

  return <Fragment>{tasks.length > 0 ? withTasks : withoutTasks}</Fragment>;
};
```

I solved this problem with this code below instead of using 2 if statements. But I'd still want to know why the code above with 2 if statements don't work.

```
const sortByBoolean = sortBy === 'true';
const filteredTasks = sortBy !== 'all' ? tasks.filter((task) => task.completed === sortByBoolean) : tasks;
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part...

```
if (sortBy === 'true' || 'false') {
  //...
}
```

...should be...

```
if (sortBy === 'true' || sortBy === 'false') {
  //...
}
```

You didn't check the condition if `sortBy` equals `'false'` but you checked the value `'false'` itself. This will return `true` because the string `'false'` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).
So currently both of your if statements are true and are executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you write two `If statements` consecutively then definately it will **execute** both of this **two**. This is the behaviour of `If statement`.

So you may used `if else if method`, also write `||` statement separately to solve this problem.

```
   if (sortBy === 'all') {
    filteredTasks = tasks;
  }
  else if (sortBy === 'true' || sortBy === 'false') {
    sortByBoolean = sortBy === 'true';
    filteredTasks = tasks.filter((task) => task.completed === sortByBoolean);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

because your if condition is not as expected because both if will be executed to skip second if when first is passed add else

```
if (sortBy === 'all') {
  filteredTasks = tasks;
} else if (sortBy === 'true' || sortBy === 'false') {
  sortByBoolean = sortBy === 'true';
  filteredTasks = tasks.filter((task) => task.completed === sortByBoolean);
}
```